# JButton positioning, does not appear

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, cardlayout

In my code I have a JFrame that opens up a main menu, in that menu you can click options, which will take you to the options menu. On that options menu I want to create a back button that will position itself somewhere in the top left corner of the screen. When I run the program and go to the options menu the JButton does not appear. Something must be wrong with my code. Any help? Below is where I first declare the JButton.

```
    static JButton optionsBackButton = new JButton("<html><font size = 5 
           color = green>Back</font></html>");
```

Here is the other part of the code that has to do with the JButton.

```
    //Options Menu
    JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel optionsOptionsTitle = new JLabel("<html><font size = 7 color = blue>Options</font></html>");
    JPanel optionsOptionsTitlePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel optionsBackButtonPanel = new JPanel();

    optionsPanel.setLayout(null);
    optionsBackButton.setBounds(100,100,50,50);

    optionsBackButtonPanel.add(optionsBackButton);
    optionsOptionsTitlePanel.add(optionsOptionsTitle);
    optionsPanel.add(optionsOptionsTitlePanel);
    optionsPanel.add(optionsBackButtonPanel);

    optionsBackButton.addActionListener(this);

    //Add panels to the card
    panel.add("Home Screen", homePanel);
    panel.add("Options Menu", optionsPanel);
    //card.add("Game screen", gamePanel);
    cardLayout.show(panel, "HomeScreen");
    contentPane.add(panel);
```

Comment: You've much to correct, including over-use of static fields, use of JFrame where a JDialog likely should be used, and most important, use of `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` where you should be using valid layout managers. To get more complete help though, post your best [mcve], and let's help you improve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is stemming from your use of `null` layouts. Note:

```
JPanel optionsBackButtonPanel = new JPanel(); // holds the back button
                                              // but never given a size

optionsPanel.setLayout(null);    // uh oh,.... bad news
optionsBackButton.setBounds(100,100,50,50);   // yes you set the bounds of the button

optionsBackButtonPanel.add(optionsBackButton);
optionsOptionsTitlePanel.add(optionsOptionsTitle);
optionsPanel.add(optionsOptionsTitlePanel);
optionsPanel.add(optionsBackButtonPanel);  // again, optionsBackButtonPanel 
                              // has been never given a size or location/bounds

optionsBackButton.addActionListener(this);
```

So you set the bounds of the button and add it to a JPanel that uses the default `FlowLayout`, and so the bounds are meaningless. Then you add that JPanel, whose bounds you never set, to a JPanel that uses null layout. So the optionsBackButtonPanel will never show.

Solution: **Don't use null layouts**, but instead learn and use the layout managers.

While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Start here: [Laying Out Components in a Container Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)